# Turkish capital letters İ and Ş do not appear on editable TCombobox field, how to force all form elements to use TURKISH_CHARSET

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Some uppercase Turkish letters such as İ and Ş do not appear ok when used on TComboBox edit area or TSpeedButton (caption).
This İ for example appears as Y with dot. Turkish lowercase letters appear just fine.

All these appear OK when used on TLabel with Default ANSI_CHARSET.
The font is same for all components, Verdana. The user has non-unicode apps region in Control Panel set to Turkish.

These uppercase letters start to work OK when COMBOBOX.font.Charset  is set to TURKISH_CHARSET;

Is there a code solution to change all elements used in all forms of app to use TURKISH_CHARSET by default?

Something like looping each Control of each form like this;

```
    if AControl is TWinControl then begin
     TwinControl(AControl).font.Charset :=TURKISH_CHARSET;
     end;
```

Problem with this code is that TWinControl does not have .FONT property..

Comment: did you try a different encoding to detect the correct language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to replace ANSI_CHARSET with DEFAULT_CHARSET  in all .DFM files

Comment: Hey, you solved it by yourself! I wonder if you get any reputation bounty for it ?